# Difference of property Delegate and Event

Tags: c#, delegates

event keyword creates two methods add_* and remove_* (its working like property).

what is the difference

```
public event MyDelegate event1;
public MyDelegate event2 { get; set; }
```

why should use event keyowrd?

Comment: to prevent `myItem.event2 = null;`, `myItem.event2 = myOther.event2;` etc. with `event` all we can do is to *add* and *remove* but not *call*, *assign* etc. dangerous operations

Answer (score 1):

One reason is *safety*. If you implement an *event* like `delegate` *field*:

```
 public MyDelegate event2 { get; set; }
```

you'll be able to do *dangerous* things:

```
 MyObject test = new MyObject();

 // removing all listeners
 test.event2 = null; 
 // just a little typo `=` instead of `+=`
 // means now complete substitution of the listeners instead of adding one  
 test.event2 = myMethod;
```